# How to resolve Gruntfile.js "unexpected token" error on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs

I cannot figure out why I can run a grunt dev build job on my local machine, but it's failing on the Jenkins server with this error:

> ```
> Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
> ```

Note that this job used to run just fine every 10 minutes on Jenkins until one day it stopped working. I wonder if something somewhere else got updated that is now breaking the build. The fact that I can run this same grunt job on my local machine OK tells me that something got updated on Jenkins that is now breaking the build only on Jenkins.

The Gruntfile.js file looks fine to me:

```js
var argv = require('yargs')
    .usage('$0 <cmd> [args]')
    .string('env')
    .required('env')
    .choices('env', ['development', 'staging'])
    .help()
    .argv;

module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var path = require('path');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var child_process = require('child_process');

    grunt.log.writeln('Using ' + argv.env);

    // Load plugins
    grunt.loadTasks('grunt/tasks');

    // Display execution time of grunt tasks
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    var buildId;

    // Load all grunt configs
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        configPath: path.join(process.cwd(), 'grunt/config'),
        postProcess: function(config) {
            // Modify path to the configuration file, without altering core grunt scripts.
            config.properties.configFile = 'build/config.' + argv.env + '.json';
            // Figure out version number
            // Get build sequence id
            var sequence = fs.readFileSync('../.buildsequence', 'utf8').replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
            var build = process.env.BUILD_NUMBER.replace(/[^0-9a-f]/g, '');
            // Get short git hash.
            var hash = child_process.execSync('git describe --always').toString().toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-f]/g, '');
            grunt.log.writeln('Git hash ' + hash);
            buildId = sequence + '-' + build + '-' + hash;
        }
    });

    grunt.log.writeln();
    grunt.log.writeln('********************************************');
    grunt.log.writeln(' -- Initializing...');

    // Load and parse configuration file(s)
    require('./grunt/lib/config/loader')(grunt);

    // Map legacy config to current format
    require('./grunt/lib/config/mapper')(grunt);

    // Normalize config (default values, correct format)
    require('./grunt/lib/config/normalizer')(grunt);

    // Avoids DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT error for self-signed certs where hostname/IP do not match
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

    var settings = grunt.config.get('settings');
    settings.project.build = buildId;
    grunt.config.set('settings', settings);

    //Output
    grunt.log.write(' -- Initialization '); grunt.log.ok();
    grunt.log.writeln();
    grunt.log.writeln(' -- Project: ' + grunt.config('settings').project.name);
    grunt.log.writeln(' -- Build: ' + grunt.config('settings').project.build);
    grunt.log.writeln(' -- Version: ' + grunt.config('properties').version.name);
    grunt.log.writeln(' -- Target:  ' + grunt.config('environment').webdav.server);
    grunt.log.writeln();
};
```

Comment: I had the same issue and it was caused by me updating grunt to v1.1.0. When I downgraded it to v1.0.4 the error was gone. Something to do with the 1.1.0 updating the mkdirp module to latest version I think.

Comment: @jerry I changed to grunt v1.0.4, but Jenkins build is still failing. Do you think it might be because grunt-cli is still v1.2.0?

Comment: it turned it was something else: the jenkins job had a npm install grunt-contrib-uglify which caused the error. It was supposed to be grunt-contrib-uglify-es. Maybe you should change modules to es version too?

Comment: @jerry I currently have this in package.json: `"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",` -- so change it to es version?

Comment: you can try that and see what happens, I'm using:
"grunt": "1.0.4",
"grunt-contrib-uglify-es": "^3.3.0"